# Размер body. Как это работает?

Tags: html, css, background, height, body

Я хочу сделать множественный фон (вода и рыба). Рыбе хочу задать определенное местоположение, например `background-position: right center`. Но замечаю, что это свойство не будет работать, пока не будут заданы width/height. Я задаю body `width: 100%`, a `height: 500px`. Но тем не менее height у меня отображается больше, чем указано. Почему так? И безопасно ли так делать, чтоб указать рыбе четкое местоположение.

```
.body { background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/85M83Lxc/f383ffc7d288687b64ea6ee11b3494c6.jpg), url(https://i.postimg.cc/fLhqVpgW/depositphotos-24216433-stock-photo-seamless-water-texture.jpg); background-size: 100px, auto; background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;background-position: right center, 0 0; width: 100%; height: 500px;}
```

[Вот мой код](https://jsfiddle.net/zt14u6gf/1/)

*Под безопасно я имею в виду не вызовет ли такой способ каких-то лагов в будущем, когда на странице будет больше элементов и контента.

Comment: Не совсем понятен суть проблемы и вопрос

Comment: А почему у body должен быть height именно 500px? куда девать остальное пространство окна браузера?

Comment: Eva, а с чего вдруг у body должен  быть height именно 500px?

Comment: вообще предпочтительно всегда высота что бы была автоматическая не только у body но и у любых тегов в html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HTML vs. BODY: Фоновое противостояние

Очень расплывчатое описание проблемы и конечного результата. Из того, что понял - Вам нужно чётко зафиксировать позицию одного из слоёв фона ("рыбка", в данном случае), чтобы независимо от размеров окна или количества контента, этот слой всегда оставался на заданной позиции (т.е. справа по центру).

Тут нужно прояснить несколько моментов:

- `<body>` зависит от размеров окна и контента (*width* по умолчанию *100%*). Следовательно, высота может меняться (если не указаны явно *height* и *overflow*), а из-за того, что позиции слоя присвоены относительные значения (*right center* = *100% 50%*), они рассчитываются исходя из размеров элемента `<body>`. Это верно, если у `<body>` свойство *background-attachment* для нужного слоя имеет значение *scroll* (значение по умолчанию);
- При `background-attachment: fixed;`, значения позиции слоя рассчитываются исходя из размеров видимой части страницы (окна просмотра). При этом размеры элементов `<body>` и `<html>` игнорируются, а всё выходящее за границы этих элементов обрезается.
- Но... Если задать множественный фон непосредственно элементу `<html>` и указать `background-attachment: fixed;` для нужных слоёв, то влияние на позиции этих слоёв будут оказывать только размеры окна просмотра. Изображения при этом не обрезаются. (При этом не забывайте явно указывать *background-color* для `<body>` - Важно! Именно прозрачный (например: *#000**0***, *rgba(0,0,0,0)* или *transparent*).

Запустите пример ниже. С помощью ползунка в верхнем левом углу, измените размер шрифта, чтобы содержимое начало растягивать страницу.

```js
/* Only for demo */ document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<input type="range" min=0.1 max=5.0 step=0.1 value=3.0 oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--fs`,`${this.value}em`);" style="position: fixed;left:0;top:0;filter:drop-shadow(0 0 2px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 7px #000);">');
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #0ff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdv5m.jpg), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRBsZ.jpg);
  background-size: 300px auto, auto auto;
  background-position: right center, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px green;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed, scroll;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlkJd.jpg), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWcv.png);
  background-size: 100px auto, 200px auto;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px red;
}

p {
  font-size: var(--fs, 3em);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Это самый средний параграф.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
```

*<sup>Если захотите что-то уточнить, то напишите в комментарии под этим ответом.</sup>*

Answer (score 2):

Особенность фона, заданного для `body - document.body` и `html - document.documentElement`, в том, что он на самом деле задаётся для document.

```css
html {
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text);
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid coral;
}
```

Соответственно позиция фона считается от него.

Comment: Почему минус? В вопросе для body задаётся высота и потом проблема что центр фона ниже чем нужно. Потому что его центр считается от элемента html, который бывает выше. Вот спецификация этого поведения - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background

Comment: не знаю кто минус влепил но я поставил плюс

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вот так делать и не думать о размерах body и height

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/85M83Lxc/f383ffc7d288687b64ea6ee11b3494c6.jpg), url(https://i.postimg.cc/fLhqVpgW/depositphotos-24216433-stock-photo-seamless-water-texture.jpg);
  background-size: 100px, auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right center, 0 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore possimus inventore, aut saepe et magnam! Blanditiis tenetur veniam adipisci praesentium veritatis voluptate quibusdam quo id? Veritatis fugit doloremque ab.</p>
```