# Как работают width/height в html и body?

Tags: html, css, height, width, body

**Width**

Мне непонятно почему если задать `width: 400px` для html, то `400рх` будет body, а не html.
Вот пример:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 400px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
</div>
```

Фон html – `orange`, body – `yellow`. Тут видно, что вне зависимости от заданной ширины html все равно растягивается на ширину всей страницы.
То есть html получается невозможно задать ширину?

**Height**

По умолчанию height у html и body auto. И для того, чтобы задать высоту body в процентах, например, надо задать конкретное значение для родителя body, то есть для html. Это все понятно.
Но вот пример.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 500px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
</div>
```

Здесь можно увидеть, что для html задана высота в `50%`. Однако, несмотря на это условие, html не отображается на половину высоты страницы, а вместо этого продолжает отображаться на всю высоту экрана.
И выходит, что для html также невозможно установить и высоту. В любом случае будет отображение на всю высоту/ширину экрана.

**Вопрос такой:** какие значения высоты и ширины у body и html по умолчанию? Чем можно объяснить такое "необычное" поведение этих свойств?

Comment: Вы с фонами разобрались - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208045/265406 ?

Comment: @UModeL фоны пока оставила, потому что поняла что в вообще не понимаю как работают тэги body и html:) мне сначала с этим разобраться надо

Comment: Если бы Вы покопались в том примере, то понимание возможно бы приблизилось. Этот вопрос тесно связан с предыдущим. Почему Вы думаете, что `<html>` не 400px ? Он ровно 400px. А так как `<body>` по умолчанию равен 100%, то он тоже принимает такой же размер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для изучения и отладки привыкайте использовать полупрозрачность для изображений и фоновых цветов, а также замените `border` на `box-shadow`, где это возможно. Вы даже не представляете, насколько это облегчит работу и сэкономит время.

По вопросу...

#### Width

Если обозначить/подсветить границы элементов `<html>` и `<body>`, а заливку не делать сплошной и непрозрачной, то можно наблюдать такую картину:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffa50088;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px green;
}

body {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ffff0088;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px red;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
</div>
```

Как видите, все указанные размеры применились правильно.

---

#### Height

Здесь та же ошибка - "если я не вижу, то этого и нет". А нет, потому что не хотите видеть. Или не знаете как и куда смотреть. В первую очередь, смотреть нужно в DevTools и инспектор стилей. Тогда можно заметить, что и тут всё сработало:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ffa50088;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px green;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
  background: #ffff0088;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px red;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut officiis explicabo similique tempore tenetur ullam iusto eos? Rem molestias minima neque ipsum saepe laudantium animi, ut, est, vitae aut unde.</p>
</div>
```

Видно, что `html` (обозначен зелёной рамкой) вполне себе 50% от окна просмотра.

*<sup>Если захотите что-то уточнить, то напишите в комментарии под этим ответом.</sup>*

Comment: Тут меня скорее сбил с пути фон, который вне зависимости от заданных размеров, расползается на всю область просмотра, ну а так спасибо

Comment: @Eva: если надо что-то уточнить, то не стесняйтесь - ваш вопрос очень широкий и нельзя на него ответить парой предложений. Если по этой же теме, то спрашивайте прямо здесь, в комментариях под ответом. Если выйдите за рамки темы, то я посоветую задать новый вопрос.

Comment: нет, спасибо. Вроде бы пока все понятно, почитала еще по этой же теме статьи в инете